# Regression calculation with missing data

Tags: regression, self-study, correlation, least-squares

In a regression calculation for five pairs of observations one pair of values was lost when data were filed. For the regression of y on x the equation was calculated as

$y=2x−0.1$

The four recorded pairs of values are:

$x:0.1,0.2,0.4,0.3$

$y:0.1,0.3,0.7,0.4$

Find the missing pair of values, using the following data for the four pairs above: $∑x=1,∑x^2=0.3,∑xy=0.47,∑y=1.5$

I managed to find out that $b=1.9$ in $y=a+bx$ when there are four values. The value of constant $a=-0.1$ remains unaltered. As such I am done with the easy part of the question. I have been thinking about simultaneous equations for a while, but again do not really know how to go about finding the values of $x_5$ and $y_5$.

I would appreciate some support that could put me on the right track.

Comment: Please consider adding the self-study tag and reading its wiki excerpt. The edit your question to tell us what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @mdewey thank you for the tip, I have updated the question a little.

Comment: This meets our standards for self-study questions: it has the tag & explains what the OP has done so far / where they need help. It should be on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct way to solve the problem is to start with simple regression equations:

$$\widehat{\beta_1}=\frac{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\text{ and }\hat{\beta_0}=\bar{y}-\widehat{\beta_1}\bar{x}$$

And of course you already have the formula for $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$.

Since you know both betas and all x and y except for two ones, you have two equations and two unknown values (x and y for the missing observation). With the sums provided by the statement you can group terms and make those equations shorter and workable.

Answer (score 0):

I have also asked this question on maths.stackexchange and got an answer from user JJacquelin. With the user's permission I have decided to repost the answer here, in case anyone stumbles upon this/similar problem.

HINT :
Before loosing one pair, the linear regression to fit the function 
$y=ax+b$ (with 5 pairs) leads to the values of $a=2$ and $b=−0.1$:

$b=\frac{∑y∑x^2−∑x∑xy}{5∑x^2-(∑x)^2}$

$a=\frac{5∑xy−∑x∑y}{5∑x^2−(∑x)^2}$

Let $(X,Y)$ be the missing pair:

$∑x=1+X;∑x^2=0.3+X^2;∑xy=0.47+XY;∑y=1.5+Y$
The $∑$
continues to be for the 5 pairs. Putting them into the above equations :

$\begin{cases}
-0.1=\frac{(1.5+Y)(0.3+X^2)−(1+X)(0.47+XY)}{5(0.3+X^2)−(1+X)^2}\\
2=\frac{5(0.47+XY)−(1+X)(1.5+Y)}{5(0.3+X^2)−(1+X)^2}\end{cases}$

Solve this system of two equations for the two unknowns 
$X,Y$.

LATTER ADDITION :
The result of solving is 
$X=0.3$, $Y=0.6$
A short way :
One observe that the pairs $(0.1,0.1)$,$(0.2,0.3)$, $(0.4,0.7)$
are exactly on the regression line 
$y=2x−0.1$

On the other hand, the pair $(0.3,0.4)$ is not on the regression line since the point should be $(0.3,0.5)$
to be on the regression line, because

$2∗0.3−0.1=0.5$
The missing pair $(X,Y)$ must compensate so that $(0.4+Y)/2=0.5→Y=0.6$